# Assigning local variable in recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have a tree and It is not a binary tree, so I want to compare all of the nodes and return the largest one, using recursion. I am having a problem of how to keep track of it, as I can't put a global variable, as it has to be local... I guess... But then if the recursion goes it resets the local variable.

```
def tree_max(node):
    max=1                                                                                     
    if node.left == None and node.right == None:
       if node.value>max:
          max=node.value
          return max
    elif node.left == None and node.right != None:
        return tree_max(node)
    elif node.left != None and node.right == None:
        return tree_max(node.left)
    else:
        return tree_max(node.left)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: First, fix the indentation.

Comment: Next, the whole point of a local variable is that it's local to the current function call. What exactly do you want here? If you want to pass the value down and back up, you need to max it a parameter (with a default value of 1). If you want to bind it into a closure, you need an inner function (with `nonlocal`, a mutable default argument, etc.).

Comment: i want a variable to keep track of my highest value, thats it

Comment: Also, don't name a variable `max`; that's the name of a built-in function.

Comment: Just FYI, your tree _is_ a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) (since each node only has two children). It's apparently not a [binary _search_ tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) (which would be sorted).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to keep the maximum value in a variable across all recursive calls, and by all means, not a *global* one. In a well-structured recursion, the result will be passed around in the return value of each recursive call. Like this:

```
def tree_max(node):
    maxleft  = float('-inf') if not node.left  else tree_max(node.left)
    maxright = float('-inf') if not node.right else tree_max(node.right)
    return max(node.value, maxleft, maxright)
```

The above assumes that `node` is not `None`, if `node` can be null then check for this condition *before* calling `tree_max()`.

Comment: but how it is gonna know which is the max value to return

Comment: @JackF: You pass it up the recursion chain.

Comment: @JackF yes, it's a built-in function to calculate the maximum in a series of values. I updated my answer again, now it's shorter

Comment: Doing comparisons based on `None` is considered bad form, since e.g. if you were doing `min` instead of `max` it'd always return `None`. In Python 3, this would raise a `TypeError`. I'd either make a list and append to it if the left/right branches exist, or maybe use `float('-inf')` instead of `None`, to be a little more explicit and portable.

Comment: @Dougal what do you suggest to use, instead of `None`? perhaps, `float('-inf')` ?

Comment: @Dougal beat me to it :) . I agree with you, fixed.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez so the maxright makes a list and keeps track of all values to the right? and then using max function finds the highest or what?

Comment: @JackF both maxright and maxleft store a simple value: the maximum value for that subtree. I'm not using lists, at all. `max()` is receiving three numbers as parameters

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I don't get it how does it know like maxright which number is the largest to store

Comment: @ÓscarLópez max() receives 3 parameters which are 3 numbers and returns the largest one, but I don't get it how maxright knows which number is the largest

Comment: @JackF that's the power of recursion in action! when you call `tree_max(node.right)`, you can be sure that the maximum number to the right will be found. Same thing to the left. Try with a small example, say a tree with 3 numbers, and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

I'd have a generator that traverses the tree. This means you can write a `min()`, `sum()` etc without duplicating the traversal logic

```
def tree_traverse(node):
    if not node.left and not node.right: # if only leaf nodes have values
        yield node.value
    if node.left:
        for v in tree_traverse(node.left):
            yield v
    if node.right:
        for v in tree_traverse(node.right):
            yield v
```

now you can just use `max(tree_traverse(node))`

if all the nodes have values, you can skip the first `if` and dedent the `yield`

as @abarnert says, Python3.3 has a nice way to simplify recursive generators

```
def tree_traverse(node):
    if not node.left and not node.right: # if only leaf nodes have values
        yield node.value
    if node.left:
        yield from tree_traverse(node.left)
    if node.right:
        yield from tree_traverse(node.right)
```

Comment: +1. Much nicer. Or, in Python 3.3, just `yield from tree_traverse(node.left)` instead of looping. But it may be a more radical change than the OP was looking for.

Comment: @abarnert, I wasn't going to bother since hardly anyone's using Python3.3 yet, but I'll add it to make the answer more useful in the future.

Comment: From my experience, there are more people using 3.3 than 3.0-3.2. (But still not as many as 2.7, unfortunately…)

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done using key word arguments e.g.

```
def tree_max(node, max=None):
```